# Create Remote Repository and Tracking in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to create a dynamic remote repository using Jenkins. This Jenkins job should take following inputs

- Name of Repository
- Location or Type (Gitlab, GitHub, Bitbucket etc.)

I tried the RestAPIs provided by [Github](https://developer.github.com/v3/), [Gitlab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/) or [Bitbucket](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/bitbucket/how-tos/command-line-rest/)

So my idea is to create a project entered by user from an input. Once name is entered then a project skeleton would be created. This skeleton would be pushed to remote git server (it can be any git based). This git server credentials would be provided by user.

So, I want to have a Jenkins job which would trigger as soon as the name would be entered. And it will create a local repository and push to remote repository.

I am new to Jenkins and tried the [Git](https://plugins.jenkins.io/git/) but not getting what I am looking for.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For what you are looking to achieve, a simple plugin will not cut it. You'll need your own groovy implementation. You can add the code in your Jenkinsfile and configure Pipeline (https://www.jenkins.io/solutions/pipeline/). Example code:

```
#!groovy

pipeline {
  parameters {
    string(name: 'repoName', defaultValue: '', description: 'Repo Name')
    choice(name: 'Location', choices: ['Github', 'GitLab', 'BitBucket'], description: 'Repo Location')
  }
  stages {
    stage('CreateRepo') {
      steps {
        echo "Creating Repo ${params.repoName} at ${params.Location}"
        createRepo(params.repoName,params.Location)
      }
    }
  }
}

def createRepo(repo, location) {
   // groovy code to create repo based on location
}
```

For Github, you can use the java/groovy library: https://github-api.kohsuke.org/